# Does not show any partition to install Ubuntu 19

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot

I am trying to install `Ubuntu 19.04` on my Windows 10 machine on a separate partition. I created unallocated space on my hard disk before the installation as follows.

[image]

Then I tried to install Ubuntu via my bootable USB drive. In the middle of the installation, at the step it asks to select the partition, I cannot see my hard disk or any other partitions. 
[image]

It shows only `/dev/sda` at Device for boot loader installation options. When I click `Intall now` button it gives an error.

[image: tu]

How can I fix this issue and install Ubuntu on my unallocated space?

Comment: I suspect your issue is due to BitLocker

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to switch your SATA operation from IDE to AHCI in BIOS.  Reboot to your USB Live install and ***CHECK*** to see if the disk is seen.  If this is the problem, changing modes will prevent Window from booting.  Reboot to BIOS and change the setting back from AHCI to IDE.

You will need to do some steps beforehand, to make sure Windows will continue to run.

- In Windows, open an administrative command prompt
- Make Windows boot to Safe Mode by typing: `bcdedit /set {current} safeboot minimal`
- Reboot the computer and enter your BIOS configuration
- Change SATA operation mode from IDE to AHCI, then save and reboot
- In Windows, open an administrative command prompt
- Return to normal booting by typing: `bcdedit /deletevalue {current} safeboot`
- Reboot your computer to verify it boots properly

Once all this is done, you can install Ubuntu.